# web page to create google maps marker icons dynamically

Tags: google-maps, icons, google-maps-markers

I found a web page where I could select a color and a range of numbers to create google maps marker icons.  Then I could download the set of icons.

I downloaded icons with numbers between 0 and 200.

Now I need to create icons between 0 and 200 in a different color but I can't find the web page.

Could you help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I have found the page you used but I did find a link collection for dynamic generated icons [icon iamge sest](http://mapki.com/wiki/Icon_Image_Sets). There are a couple of dead links among them so it might be that "your" was among them.
But maybe you can find something else you can use there.